# overload 'in' operator

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading

In Groovy, I can write code such as:

```
assert 1 in [1,2,3]
assert "foo" in "foo"
assert 2 in 1..4
```

Is there some way that I can overload the 'in' operator for my own classes? If so, which method should I implement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overload the isCase method, ie:

```
class Example {
  def isCase( o ) {
    true
  }
}

def c = new Example()
println( "woo" in c )
```

prints `true`

Answer (score 1):

The ["in" operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators) is based on the `contains()` method.